# Do I have to file a tax return for 2017 if my only income was a tax refund?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, non-resident, income-tax-refund

In 2016 I did a summer internship at a technology firm in California. Came from Europe on a J1 visa. Filed a 1040NR-EZ, and got a tax refund in 2017.

Now, as I understand, state tax refund is taxable income if I used "Itemized Deductions" which I believe I did. So, it seems that my US income for 2017 totals to less than 2k$.

I read that below a certain amount one generally is not obliged to file a return, as they would not owe any tax anyway.

My question is: is the above reasoning correct (especially considering my status as a non-resident alien), and I simply don't have to do anything?

Additional details: in 2016 on 1040NR-EZ I entered my state tax on the line 11 (Itemized Deductions), and so it decreased my taxable income on that form, I assumed that what it means to itemize. Then I got tax refunds for both state and federal taxes. I don't think I "deducted the amount being returned" on any US form, that would be weird as I were filing them *before* the actual refunds, right?

Comment: Generally filing a tax return no matter whether you owe or get a refund is meant to protect you and avoid undue audits for missing it, so it doesn't hurt for you to do it if for nothing else than that, since it will be an EZ, it won't cost you anything but a few minutes of your time and is worthwhile. Good luck.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ If the OP has a taxable refund, he is ineligible for the EZ.

Comment: What's an EZ? Does it refer to a simplified version of a tax return, like 1040NR-EZ?

Comment: @BenMiller he has a return income, and unless he has other income to put him over the limit or decided to itemize, yes he can still do an EZ, having a return income in no way changes that.

Comment: @Brythan normal or whether it is here, are two different discussions and you are welcome to debate that. But we are answering the OP and his context. Again, if such an exception applies here depends on more information than is presented, and he will have to look into that. But simply based on the information provided, he can file the EZ and report everything and be done with it.

Comment: Will you guys *please* stop calling a tax refund a “return”. (The question uses the terms correctly.)

Comment: @Brythan: 1040NR-EZ _does_ handle refund of (deducted) state/local tax, see line 4; it is _resident_ 1040EZ that does not.

Comment: @user102008 The question has been marked as already answered, so just to make sure - is the answer "yes, you have to file a return"? Even though *normally* people with income this low would not have to (according to what I've read on the internet, at least)?